# Python. Обязательные, не обязательные аргументы функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

допустим есть функция:

```
def func(a=None, b):
    return b
```

Как я могу запустить функцию, вводя только параметр `b`?
При запуске данного кода func(2), где 2 я хочу записать на место `b`.

Comment: А что если такая функция def func(a=None, b=None), как соблюсти нормальный порядок без указывания параметра при запуске функции?

Comment: Ты указываешь все подряд слева → направо. Именно поэтому у тебя все которые ты можешь НЕ указать идут в конце. Тебе надо указывать подряд без пропусков. Слева направо, указываешь все до последнего указываемого аргумента. К примеру, в функции `def func(a=None, b=None, c=None)` если ты хочешь указать ТОЛЬКО `b` равное `RAINGM` тебе все равно надо написать `func(None, RAINGM)`. А вот `c` можно и опустить, оно СПРАВА.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже написал *Gh0sTG0*, если аргументы вводятся в виде значений, то важен порядок.

Ваш исходный вариант:

```
def func(a=None, b):
    return b
```

будет выдавать `SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`. Для интерпретатора важен порядок, чтобы переменные без значений по-умолчанию шли перед переменными с дефолтными значениями.

Другой момент, когда у нас очередность соблюдена, а мы в функции задаем переменные через присваивание. Все три варианта будут отработаны:

```
def func1(a, b):
    print(a, b)

def func2(a=None, b=None):
    print(a, b)

def func3(a, b=None):
    print(a, b)

func1(b=10, a=15)
func2(b=10, a=15)
func3(b=10, a=15)
```

С учетом этого в вашем случае можно, к примеру, задать все переменные со значениями по-умолчанию

```
def func(a=None, b=None)
```

а потом вызывать

```
func(b=10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Сначала идут все обязательные аргументы (те которые без `=None`, просто буквами/названиями, к примеру `(a, very_usefull_argument)`, и.т.п.), потом идут те аргументы которые можно не вводить. Т.е. в твоей задаче это будет как:

```
def func(b, a=None):
    return b


t = func(5)
print(t)  #выведет 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Именно так функцию нельзя записать, будет синтаксическая ошибка - именованные параметры должны идти после позиционных.

Но в целом можно сделать как-то так, хотя это и изврат какой-то на вид:

```
def func(a, b):
    return b

def func2(b):
    return func_(None, b)

func_ = func
func = func2
func(2)
```

Наверное, можно и декоратор сделать, чтобы более красиво, но это надо подумать.

Comment: *>Наверное, можно и декоратор сделать* - `functools.partial`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Да, но для именованных аргументов. Хотя, может и для позиционных можно его использовать, надо посмотреть.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала идут обязательные параметры которые перечисляются литерами, потом не обязательные, у них после литеры идет `=`

```py
def func(b, a="'some value or None'"):
    print(b, a)
    return b

print(func(1))
print(func(1, "'another value'"))
```

Вот так работать будет.